# VS Code генерирует импорт модуля JavaScript, а node не может его найти

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Например я хочу использовать класс Man в файле man.js.
Я выделяю Man и через контекстное меню генерирую строку

```
import {Man} from "./man"
```

Node.js же хочет увидеть расширение .js в пути.
Но я не хочу каждый раз дописывать
".js" ко всем модулям.

Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Comment: Возможно это ваш случай. Посмотрите ответ от mateus-s-machado https://stackoverflow.com/a/57558982/7523969

Comment: Действительно мой случай, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо UserTest013: нужно запускать с параметром `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node`

Answer (score -1):

Таким образом будет работать:

```
const Man = require('./man')
```

Comment: Это переделывать весь проект. Добавить через замену к пути.js я ещё могу, но предложенный способ к тому же абсолютно не решает проблему с тем, что vscode и node не дружат)

Comment: У меня в Node.js работает мой способ. Возможно помогает расширение Path Intellisense.